# Grouping python list of dictionaries and aggregation value data

Tags: python, dictionary, grouping

I have input list

```
inlist = [{"id":123,"hour":5,"groups":"1"},{"id":345,"hour":3,"groups":"1;2"},{"id":65,"hour":-2,"groups":"3"}]
```

I need to group the dictionaries by 'groups' value. After that I need to add key min and max of hour in new grouped lists. The output should look like this

```
outlist=[(1, [{"id":123, "hour":5, "min_group_hour":3, "max_group_hour":5}, {"id":345, "hour":3, "min_group_hour":3, "max_group_hour":5}]),
     (2, [{"id":345, "hour":3, "min_group_hour":3, "max_group_hour":3}])
     (3, [{"id":65, "hour":-2, "min_group_hour":-2, "max_group_hour":-2}])]
```

So far I managed to group input list

```
new_list = []
for domain in test:
    for group in domain['groups'].split(';'):
        d = dict()
        d['id'] = domain['id']
        d['group'] = group
        d['hour'] = domain['hour']
        new_list.append(d)

for k,v in itertools.groupby(new_list, key=itemgetter('group')):
    print (int(k),max(list(v),key=itemgetter('hour'))
```

And output is

```
('1', [{'group': '1', 'id': 123, 'hour': 5}])
('2', [{'group': '2', 'id': 345, 'hour': 3}])
('3', [{'group': '3', 'id': 65, 'hour': -2}])
```

I don't know how to aggregate values by group? And is there more pythonic way of grouping dictionaries by key value that needs to be splitted?

Comment: Use `pandas dataframe` to insert these values and do a aggregate query on top of it

Comment: @goRunToStack, are you open to `pandas` ?

Comment: @jpp no, I haven't opened it in pandas. But this is good start point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by creating a dict that maps group numbers to dictionaries:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dicts_by_group = defaultdict(list)
for dic in inlist:
    groups = map(int, dic['groups'].split(';'))
    for group in groups:
        dicts_by_group[group].append(dic)
```

This gives us a dict that looks like

```
{1: [{'id': 123, 'hour': 5, 'groups': '1'},
     {'id': 345, 'hour': 3, 'groups': '1;2'}],
 2: [{'id': 345, 'hour': 3, 'groups': '1;2'}],
 3: [{'id': 65, 'hour': -2, 'groups': '3'}]}
```

Then iterate over the grouped dicts and set the `min_group_hour` and `max_group_hour` for each group:

```
outlist = []
for group in sorted(dicts_by_group.keys()):
    dicts = dicts_by_group[group]
    min_hour = min(dic['hour'] for dic in dicts)
    max_hour = max(dic['hour'] for dic in dicts)

    dicts = [{'id': dic['id'], 'hour': dic['hour'], 'min_group_hour': min_hour,
              'max_group_hour': max_hour} for dic in dicts]
    outlist.append((group, dicts))
```

Result:

```
[(1, [{'id': 123, 'hour': 5, 'min_group_hour': 3, 'max_group_hour': 5},
      {'id': 345, 'hour': 3, 'min_group_hour': 3, 'max_group_hour': 5}]),
 (2, [{'id': 345, 'hour': 3, 'min_group_hour': 3, 'max_group_hour': 3}]),
 (3, [{'id': 65, 'hour': -2, 'min_group_hour': -2, 'max_group_hour': -2}])]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC: Here is another way to do it in `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

input = [{"id":123,"hour":5,"group":"1"},{"id":345,"hour":3,"group":"1;2"},{"id":65,"hour":-2,"group":"3"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(input)
#Get minimum
dfmi = df.groupby('group').apply(min)
#Rename hour column as min_hour
dfmi.rename(columns={'hour':'min_hour'}, inplace=True)
dfmx = df.groupby('group').apply(max)
#Rename hour column as max_hour
dfmx.rename(columns={'hour':'max_hour'}, inplace=True)
#Merge min df with main df
df = df.merge(dfmi, on='group', how='outer')
#Merge max df with main df
df = df.merge(dfmx, on='group', how='outer')
output = list(df.apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(), axis=1))
#Dictionary of dictionaries
dict_out = df.to_dict(orient='index')
```